# Why is my Elastic Beanstalk application created through the CLI not showing up on the online AWS Elastic Beanstalk console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Following this tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_symfony2.html

Application URL works with Hello World and I see the data in the S3 console.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

School boyed it. Top right I needed to select the correct region, it defaulted to Oregon.

Appending this graphic to your answer rather then writing a new one.

[image]

Comment: lol too funny. did the same thing 4 years later. HAHAH poor UI.

Comment: haha love how I'm cranking up SO rep points for the simplest problem

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I realized my issue after I had an RDS connected to the wrong EB instance and the database just wasn't working for some reason... I searched everywhere with queries for postgresql and rails and everything, when the problem was I connected my RDS to the wrong instance. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are logged into separate accounts for the cli (terminal / command line) and the console (browser).

You can select a particular user by specifying the named profile.

For example

`eb init --profile nameofprofile`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-profile